# How to make my custom listview be expandable listview

Tags: android

I have created a list view with a custom baseAdapter (my own class extends it) and everything looks good.

However, I am thinking about making this list expanadable( basicallay when you click on list item, it expands to show children).
How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this

http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html